# Look and feel of legend in lattice plots

Tags: r, lattice

I'm looking for 1) more vertical space between "A", "B" and "C", "\n" is not a solution Iam lokking for. 2) I want to change the plotting order of symbols and text. That means, first I want to plot the lines of the legend and after that text.

```
 attach(mtcars)
 gear.f<-factor(gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
 labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears"))
 cyl.f <-factor(cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
 labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl"))

 densityplot(~mpg|cyl.f,
      main="Density Plot by Number of Cylinders",
      xlab="Miles per Gallon"
     ,par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col=c(1,2,3)))
     ,auto.key=list(corner = c(.98, .02),text = c("A", "B", "C")
                   ,lines=T,points=F)
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is better from an aesthetic viewpoint but you can move it around to suit you sensibilities by altering the 'x' and 'y' arguments to the key parameter:

```
 densityplot(~mpg|cyl.f,
      main="Density Plot by Number of Cylinders",
      xlab="Miles per Gallon"
     ,par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col=c(1,2,3)))
     ,key = list(lines = list(col=c("black", "red", "green")),
                  text = list(c("A", "B", "C")), x=0.8, y=0.8, corner.x=0,corner.y=0 )
            )
```

I do not think you can  do it with 'auto.key' or 'simpleKey'.)

Comment: Thx! When I export this plot with tikzDevice I get a framed legend, is there key to do not print the frame? Also there is a frame around the whole graphic, can I turn it off?

Comment: Use `border=FALSE` in the key-list to suppress the legend border. I think you will need to review the tikzDevice documentation since there is no frame with the two other more "typical devices"  I just tried.

Comment: If I try the following example, legend and whole graphic are framed   
     tikz('./test.tex',width=5, height=5, standAlone=TRUE)
     densityplot(~mpg|cyl.f
     ,layout=c(3,1)
     ,par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col=c(1,2,3)))
     ,key = list(lines = list(col=c("black", "red", "green")),
                  text = list(c("A", "B", "C"))
                  , x=0.8, y=0.1
                  ,border=F
                  
                  )
            )
     dev.off()

Comment: Installed a new version of tikzDevice from source. Am not seeing the features you are describing on my machine (Mac, Snow leopard, R 2.15.1,  tikzDevice v0.6.2-92-0ad2792). The output with the code above is 3 panels side-by-side, with no border around either the legend or the graphic. (The legend is poorly placed.)  I think you need to deal directly with the maintainers.